# Generate git https credentials for an iam user using cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am currently creating IAM users with no login profile using cloudformation template files. I am attempting to automate the user creation and access to codecommit repo. But I couldn't find a way to create https git credentials for an IAM user. Can someone please let me know if its achievable using cloudformation template or from lambda?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no way to do this with a CloudFormation resource.

You can with Lambda, using the [CreateServiceSpecificCredential](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_CreateServiceSpecificCredential.html) API call. You pass it the user's IAM username and the service name, which in this case is `codecommit.amazonaws.com`. It returns a username and password for use with the service.

Comment: Can you please let me know if there is an example that i can refer to?

Comment: I don't know of any examples, but it's a simple-enough call.